# How can i scrape the google search result 2nd page only?

Tags: php, web-scraping, scrape

I'm having trouble on scraping the second page of the google search result,  After scraping the result it will save the page on the file. It only scrape the first page.
Here is my code:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='.$in;
$datenbank = "proxy_work.php"; 
$datei = fopen($datenbank,"w+");
$datenbank = "proxy_work.php";
fwrite($datei, $url);  
fwrite ($datei,"\r\n");
fclose($datei);
// echo file_get_contents("proxy_work.php");
$html = file_get_html("proxy_work.php");
foreach($html->find('a') as $e){
    //  $title = $h3->innertext;
    $link  = $e->href;
    //  if(in_array($endomain, $approveurl)){
            // 
        }
    // if it is not a direct link but url reference found inside it, then extract
    if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link) && preg_match('/q=(.+)&amp;sa=/U', $link, $matches) && preg_match('/^https?/', $matches[1])) {
        $link = $matches[1];
    } else if (!preg_match('/^https?/', $link)) { // skip if it is not a valid link
        continue;
    } 
}
```

Comment: you can (depending on your search results per page, which by default is 10 I believe) use query parameter `start=` to go to the next page in search results, i.e.: `https://www.google.com/search?q=hello&start=10` gives page 2, `https://www.google.com/search?q=hello&start=20` gives page 3 of search results.

Comment: Another question what should i do if i start the search result on page 1 and ends on page 2 only. is it possible?